# What does @property(retain) do?

Tags: objective-c, retain

What does @propert(retain) do? it doesn't actually retain my object by my tests:

```
id obj = getObjectSomehow();
NSLog(@"%d", [obj retainCount]);
propertyWithRetain = obj;
NSLog(@"%d", [obj retainCount]);

// output:
// 1
// 1
```

How can I make a property that will really retain the object?

Comment: I don't see any property being set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not using your property there, that's why it's not retaining!

Try this :

```
id obj = getObjectSomehow();
NSLog(@"%d", [obj retainCount]);
self.propertyWithRetain = obj; // Note the self. :)
NSLog(@"%d", [obj retainCount]);
```

Using `self.` will use the property. Just using the variable name won't.

---

EDIT especially for @bbum (who raises a very fair point in the comments)

Don't rely on using retainCount - you don't know what else has retained your object and you don't know if some of those retains are actually scheduled autoreleases so it's usually a misleading number :)

Comment: +1 otherwise the setter will always result in a stack overflow. :)

Comment: Point if you mentioned the evils of retainCount. :)

Comment: That did the trick. Where did `propertyWithRetain` pop from in local context?

Comment: @WTP wut? I see no infinite loop.

Comment: Expanded my answer to indicate where `propertyWithRetain` came from;  it isn't in the local scope at all.

Comment: @bbum well, if just using the variable would be using the setter, the setter cannot be made without calling itself: recursion/stack overflow.

Comment: Just great, now have to add `self.` in 293042830 places. at least `@synthesize propertyWithRetain = propertyWithRetain_` helped finding them.

Comment: @WTP It is quite easy to make the compiler treat bare property references as a call to the setter (as long as the setter is synthesized).  There was a prototype that did exactly that, but it was a stupid resulting experience and nixed in favor of the behavior we have (partially because, yes, creating a custom setter required a function call whereas everything else did not).

Answer (score 2):

```
propertyWithRetain = obj;
```

That just sets the ivar backing the property directly.  When an @property is synthesized, if there is no instance variable declared, then one is generated automatically.   The above is using that ivar directly.

```
self.propertyWithRetain = obj;
```

That would actually go through the `@synthesize`d setter and bump the retain count.

Which is also why many of us use `@synthesize propertyWithRetain = propertyWithRetain_;` to cause the iVar to be named differently.

Note that, even in this, calling `retainCount` can be horribly misleading.  Try it with `[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2];` or a constant string.  Really, don't call `retainCount`.  Not ever.

Comment: Yea I noticed the `MAX_INT` ones, have no idea why. just tried on a object that was sane.

Comment: That is why you should never call `retainCount`; the absolute value is an internal implementation detail and often a value that makes no sense.