# objective-c retain , assign and copy?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, retain, assign

I deleted the previous post ...

Which one do i use if I have a class that owns an object objA? I know if the object wasn't own by the class,it needs to be retained.

```
@class A

@property (retain) ObjectA objA;

@end

@implementation A

-(void) func {
   self.objA = [[ObjectA alloc] init];
}

@end
```

If objA in class A is set as a retain, and was initialized in func using init function. Would this give 2 retain count or just 1 retain count.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does @property(retain) do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360499/what-does-propertyretain-do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alloc gives retain count 1.
self.objA = will give retain count 2 (because of the retain property)

Answer (score 0):

I would have done :

```
   - (void) func {objA = [[ObjectA alloc] init]; }
```

or

```
   - (void) func { self.objA = [[[ObjectA alloc] init] autorelease]; }
```

to prevent memory leaks. However I prefer the first solution